# From Google Sheets into React Grid

Tags: reactjs, devextreme, react-grid-layout

How can I do in REACT if I want to connect Google Sheets as a remote source into [React Grid](https://devexpress.github.io/devextreme-reactive/react/grid/docs/guides/getting-started/) (from DevEstreme)?

Answer (score 0):

Well, DevExtream Reactive Grid can work with data only in the following format:

```
 <Grid
    rows={[
      { id: 0, product: 'DevExtreme', owner: 'DevExpress' },
      { id: 1, product: 'DevExtreme Reactive', owner: 'DevExpress' },
    ]}
    columns={[
      { name: 'id', title: 'ID' },
      { name: 'product', title: 'Product' },
      { name: 'owner', title: 'Owner' },
    ]}>
    <Table />
  </Grid>
```

You need to associate a column with a row field using the column’s `name` field. It means that if you could get data from your Google Sheet (e.g. as in [Google Sheets API - Reading and Writing Values](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values)) and modify them according to this, you will be able to display them.

If you need an automatical connection, the answer is no. Reactive Grid accepts only this data format. Otherwise, you need to process data manually.